# How can I deploy a crate cluster on Giant Swarm?

Tags: docker, crate, giant-swarm

I have been trying to set up a working crate cluster on Giant Swarm for quite a while now but haven't been really successfull so far.

Here are my attempts so far:

- Using multicast and deploying crate as a single component. This works if all instances of this component end up on the same host, unfortunately this isn't reliable.
- Using unicast with two components, which each expose port `4300` via url. This results in messages being received by each component in the discovery interval ( every 30 secounds by default ). Unfortunately Giant Swarm only supports `HTTP` on its urls, so all messages that are error messages from something other than `HTTP` being sent by the component.
- Using unicast with two components and trying to discover them via their `IPs`. I set up Giant Swarm dependencies from one component to the other (circular dependencies are not supported). I can't get this to work because Giant Swarm doesn't allow me to run scripts before the docker container is created ( which is used in [this blog post to run crate on the google cloud platform](https://crate.io/blog/deploying-crate-with-docker-machine-swarm/) ) and docker does not [support bidirectional linking.](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2588)

I am out of ideas at this point, is there something I am missing about either crate or Giant Swarm? The only example I saw so far of something similar working was the [blog post](https://crate.io/blog/deploying-crate-with-docker-machine-swarm/) I linked above and it uses a mechanic I cannot use on Giant Swarm.

I would appreciate any kind of input on how to make this work or ideas leading in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current (May 2015) answer is: On a private Giant Swarm cluster, which we provide to customers on request, we support Multicasting. So the road is paved there for Crate.IO clustering.

We use [Weave](http://weave.works) for the networking part.

**Edit September 2015:** We just published a [blog post](https://blog.giantswarm.io/deploy-elastic-high-availability-sql-cluster-crate-weave/) explaining how to set up a Crate cluster on Giant Swarm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that it is not possible to deploy a Crate cluster (>1 node) on Giant Swarm at the moment (due to reasons you've mentioned). We (Crate.IO) are already in contact with Giant Swarm regarding that.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer until a new update regarding this issue is deployed.

Comment: @Bricktop Please check out the blog post on the subject we just published. See the URL in my answer.